# Django - Preventing translation of available language names in template

Tags: django, django-i18n

I have my available languages in settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)
```

When i loop in my template, I think it is the expected behavior that  django gives me the translated names via {{ lang.1 }}. But i don't want lang names to be translated so i have changed my settings.py as below:

```
LANGUAGES = (
        ('fr', 'Francais'),
        ('en', 'English'),
    )
```

I am still getting translated lang names. Do you have an idea? 
Does {% get_available_languages as languages %} template tag automatically translates the list items? If so how can i use untranslated language names while looping in available languages?

---- EDIT ---

I have checked the code of get_available_languages template tag of django.
I think it is translated here:

```
class GetAvailableLanguagesNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.variable = variable

    def render(self, context):
        context[self.variable] = [(k, translation.ugettext(v)) for k, v in settings.LANGUAGES]
        return ''
```

Maybe i have to write my own template tag...

Comment: Have you run runserver again?

Comment: Yes i run my server again...

Comment: if i write  ('en', 'test'), for example it works and gives 'test' as expected...

Comment: Seems like you have answered your own question. You should just write your own template tag, or access settings.LANGUAGES directly.

Answer (score 5):

**No Hacks, this time**

According to the [translation documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/) you can use the available language tools either in the template or in the python code.

In the template, using the [get_language_info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#get-language-info) template tag:

```
{% get_language_info for "pl" as lang %}

Language code: {{ lang.code }}<br />
Name of language: {{ lang.name_local }}<br />
Name in English: {{ lang.name }}<br />
Bi-directional: {{ lang.bidi }}
Name in the active language: {{ lang.name_translated }}
```

which can be combined with other tags and build a mechanism that allows you to [change languages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates):

```
{% for lang_code, lang_name in languages %}  
   {% if lang_code != LANGUAGE_CODE %}      
     {% get_language_info for lang_code as lang_info %}
     {% language lang_code %}                            
     {% url request.resolver_match.url_name as no_slug %}
     {% url request.resolver_match.url_name slug=object.slug as yes_slug %}  
     <p>Link to: {% firstof yes_slug no_slug %} Local name: {{ lang_info.name_local }}</p>
     {% endlanguage %}
   {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34365599/2996101) the same result is achieved in the view.

Otherwise, you can use [get_language_info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#localized-names-of-languages) in your code as follows:

```
>>>from django.utils.translation import get_language_info
>>>li = get_language_info('en')
>>>print(li)
{'bidi': False, 'code': 'en', 'name': 'English', 'name_local': 'English'}
```

and use it in the context of the [following example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#using-translations-outside-views-and-templates):

```
from django.utils import translation

def welcome_translated(language):
    cur_language = translation.get_language()
    try:
        translation.activate(language)
        text = translation.ugettext('welcome')
    finally:
        translation.activate(cur_language)
    return text
```

---

> if i write ('en', 'test'), for example it works and gives 'test' as
>   expected

Thank you! This idea brought forward the following <del>solution</del> hack:

```
LANGUAGES = (
        ('fr', 'Francais'),
        ('en', ' English'),
    )
```

Notice the space added before the word English.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (wanting the language names in their own translation) and simply redefined the languages variable in views before passing it to the template:

```
   from django.utils.translation import get_language_info
   languages = [(lang[0], get_language_info(lang[0])['name_local'] for lang in settings.LANGUAGES]
```

That basically allows to have quickly a variable of language codes and names in their own translation, namely :

```
   [('en', 'English'), ('fr', 'Français')]
```

I guess the same line would do the job in a custom template tag. Hope it helps !