# django i18n - get current path for different language

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-i18n, django-template-filters

I am using Django and developing an i18n site serving many languages. I want to make a modal that stays in base.html, so that users can switch the language wherever they are.

I managed to do something like this.

```
<div class="modal-body">
{% get_available_languages as languages %}
    {% for lang_code, lang_name in languages %}
        {% language lang_code %}
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn lang-btn {% ifequal request.LANGUAGE_CODE lang_code %}selected{% endifequal %}">{{lang_code|lang_name}}</a>
        {% endlanguage %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Which turns out urls like:`/ja/`, `/en/`, `/fr/`, etc..
but this kind of approach links to the main page only.

When using `{{request.path}}` or `{{request.get_full_path}}` for the url like:

```
<a href="{{ request.path }}" class="btn lang-btn {% ifequal request.LANGUAGE_CODE lang_code %}selected{% endifequal %}">{{lang_code|lang_name}}</a>
```

It doesn't include the i18n url patterns..

Is there any way for directing current url with request.path??

**TARGET**

When in `/foo/` : `/ja/foo/` `/en/foo/` `/fr/foo/`

When in `/bar/` : `/ja/bar/` `/en/bar/` `/fr/bar/`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This topic is discussed in this SO question: [Django templates: Get current URL in another language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437454/django-templates-get-current-url-in-another-language).

In my project, I use this simple template tag (taken from https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2875/), which returns the URL of the current view in another language.

**`foo/templatetags/i18n_urls.py`:**

```
from django import template
from django.urls import translate_url

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def change_lang(context, lang: str, *args, **kwargs):
    path = context['request'].path

    return translate_url(path, lang)
```

**`some_template.html`:**

```
{% load i18n_urls %}

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="{% change_lang 'en' %}">EN</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{% change_lang 'cs' %}">CS</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{% change_lang 'de' %}">DE</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please note that `translate_url` function is not documented in the official Django docs. Here is the source code of this function: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/base.py#L161-L181.

Comment: I used your code and finally made it. It worked when I rooted out the `{% language %}` template tag and only adjusted your snippet. Thanks!