# set_language not changing language in certain cases (django)

Tags: django, django-i18n

I have the following menu to change languages in my site:

```
<div class="btn-group navbar-right language menu">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle language-btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        {% get_language_info for LANGUAGE_CODE as lang %}
        {{ lang.name_local }} ({{ lang.code }})
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">

        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}

        {% for language in languages %}
            <ul class="language-item">
              <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />
                <input name="language" type="hidden" value="{{ language.code }}" />
                <input type="submit" value="{{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})" /> <span>{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}✓{% endif %}</span>
              </form>
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </div> 
</div>
```

Being shown like

[image: Menu for changing languages]

This works the same than [the form suggested by Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) but avoiding the "Go" button to switch languages.

It usually switches languages properly, except in certain cases, as I found out after a user reported the problem.

If the user gets to my site via `www.mydomain.com`, it will be redirected to `www.mydomain.com/en/` (or `/es/` or `/de/`) and as far as I know, changing languages works as expected.

However, if the user gets to my site via `www.mydomain.com/es/`, then when trying to change the language through the menu, `www.mydomain.com/es/` is loaded again. The same behavior occurs with `www.mydomain.com/de/`.

Strange enough, when entering my site via `www.mydomain.com/en/`, changing languages works properly. Maybe because it is the default language?

I am able to replicate the issue consistently if entering the site through an incognito window. If I do it through a normal window, it is a similar behavior, but not always consistent. For instance, sometimes entering via `www.mydomain.com/en/` will not let me change the language either. This makes me think it might have something to do with cookies. But this is as far as I got.

I checked for similar problems during hours and the only similar thing I found is the Django ticket [In some cases i18n set_language does not change url language](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29281). Its conclusion is:

> ...I recreated the issue: we set a language (once) then try to reverse
>   a URL from the old language when setting the language again.
>
> This obviously fails.
>
> Workarounds:
>
> - keeping track of the old language and falling back to try that if the lookup with the current language fails.
> - Signalling across browser tabs that we already changed the language and adjusting accordingly (???).
>
> Both of these are out of scope for the in-built i18n. (The first would
>   be possible on a project level — reimplementing e.g. set_language — if
>   it was deemed cost effective.)
>
> I'm going to close this on that basis.

I am not sure if it is the same case, as I don't understand why it "obviously fails". As I see it, the obvious behavior should be to change the language.

I am surprised that such a basic feature does not work, so probably I am missing something.

Why is it not working in the cases described?
Any help would be appreciated.

---

Edit 1:

Previously I was using translated URLs instead of the form, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21573776/5802289). However, this was taking 1 second to render due to the translation of the slug. This is why I decided to change

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem. It is still an existing issue, where django seemingly does not translate the HTTP referer header.

[See Django source code of set_language](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/i18n.py#L23)

A way to workaround this is to send a hidden input field named `next` that you set to the same url you are at (`request.get_full_path`), but replace the current language part with the language you intend to switch to.

Here is a snippet of a language switcher solving this issue:

```
    <li {% if current_language|slice:":2"  == 'en' %} class="active"{% endif %}>
      <form method="POST" action="{% url 'set_language' %}" autocomplete="off">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <span class="language-code">en</span>
        <input type="submit" name="language" value="en">
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path|replace_language:"en" }}">
      </form>
    </li>
    <li{% if current_language|slice:":2" == 'da' %} class="active"{% endif %}>
      <form method="POST" action="{% url 'set_language' %}" autocomplete="off">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <span class="language-code">dk</span>
        <input type="submit" name="language" value="da">
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path|replace_language:"da" }}">
      </form>
    </li>
```

Then you can implement a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) called replace_language that runs through your configured languages and replaces it with the argument.

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by removing the language code from the "next" input (slice the current language code from the url)

Next input:
`<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path|slice:"3:" }}">`

Whole dropdown:

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row g-2">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
      <div class="form-floating">
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path|slice:"3:" }}">
        <select class="form-select" name="language" onchange="this.form.submit()" id="language">
          {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
          {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
          {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
          {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
              {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <label for="language">Language</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For further reference, I just went back to using translated URLs as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437454/django-templates-get-current-url-in-another-language/21573776#21573776), instead of the form.

I found out that what was making it so slow.
It turned out it was something that could be optimized, so now the translated URLs load very fast as well.