# How to make Django messages framework play nicely with i18n?

Tags: python, django, django-i18n, django-messages, django-4.0

Using django 4.0.6 I was using the messages framework to display messages when users successfully completed a form. Then I added i18n:

When the default language is selected, messages are shown on the second screen after the form is submitted, not the first.

When the not-default language is active, untranslated messages are shown, on the first screen after the message is created (as expected).

I've tried using both `gettext_lazy` and `gettext` and it didnt help.

Its an unusual bug and Im not sure what I've done wrong?

views:

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
...

class ContactView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):

    template_name = "contact-form.html"
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("base:home")
    success_message = _("Thanks for contacting us.")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if contact_form_filter(form):
            create_and_send_contact_form_email(form)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        """If the form is invalid, render the invalid form."""
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

settings:

```py
TIME_ZONE = "CET"
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en"
USE_I18N = True
WAGTAIL_I18N_ENABLED = True
USE_L10N = True  # Deprecated in Django 4, but still used in Wagtail I believe
USE_TZ = True

WAGTAIL_CONTENT_LANGUAGES = LANGUAGES = [
    ("en", _("English")),
    ("nl", _("Dutch")),
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "django.contrib.messages",
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware",
    "compression_middleware.middleware.CompressionMiddleware",
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [str(APPS_DIR / "built"), str(APPS_DIR / "templates")],
        "OPTIONS": {
            "loaders": [
                "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
                "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
            ],
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.template.context_processors.media",
                "django.template.context_processors.static",
                "django.template.context_processors.tz",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "lettergun.utils.context_processors.settings_context",
                "lettergun.utils.context_processors.pass_",
                "lettergun.utils.context_processors.toggle_customer_testimonials",
            ],
        },
    }
]
```

Comment: I believe you add the message through `create_and_send_contact_form_email`, and this code isn't provided.

Comment: no @Blackeagle52, they use  SuccessMessageMixin, it is ok.

Comment: Oh wow, this exists, never knew about it.. How to support lazy people. Then I retreat, I probably miss way more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problems and the site now behaves consistently and as expected. The odd behavior was caused by two issues:

1. The order of middleware is important.
2. Take care that any custom template tags that are used to set or switch the site language are not creating side effects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73050572/6553466) for this specific issue.

I set the middleware to the below and messages and translations now work as expected:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
]
```

Comment: in 2. you take completely wrong approach.

Answer (score -1):

Translations together with messages is a very interesting thing.

Every `message` in `messages` dictionary wait till own render through {`{ messages }}` in template.

It means, if next template don't have this tag - you can not see the messages and they can not be rendered and they should wait.

A `lazy_translation` is a `wrapper` that does nothing until the `str/unicode` function for that translation is called. In your case - message has `lazy_translation`, and they wait `render` call.

Let's try - choose language. Open the from. Fill the form. Press Save. Close the browser before you see the answer.

Your messages still waiting the moment to render self. Lasy_translation wait too.

Open your browser, open completely other link with other language. If template has `{{ messages }}`, you see the old message with old info from other view with translation on the current language.

If you change `lazy_translation` on `gettext` - and made the same process. You should see the message with old language.

My opinion. Every should override `get_success_message` function and wrap `super().get_success_message` in `str`. It's made the expected behavior of translations in messages.

The next question - why you not see the `messages`. I need more information about view and templates to answer.

Comment: All templates have a templates tag.

Comment: i add more description.