# Django reloading a page without losing user inputs in a form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, translation

I am working on translating my project.

I implemented a language switch in my basetemplate:

```html
{% load i18n %}
{% load language_tags %}
<!-- imports all tags from templatetags/language_tags.py (see below) -->
...
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        {% translate 'Language' %}
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
      {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
      {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as langs %}
      {% for lang in langs %}
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% translate_url lang.code %}">{{lang.name_local}}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div> 
...
```

The important part here is the `href={% translate_url lang.code %}`.
It is a custom template tag (see **templatetags/language_tags.py**) in my project that I have from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17351858/21828018

Its usage (`{% translate_url de %}`) is to give back the url you are visiting in the given language;
e.g. if you are visiting **en/product/product_id** and you use `{% translate_url de %}` it returns **de/product/product_id**. In combination with **i18n_patterns** the translation works so far.

**templatetags/language_tags.py:**

```py
"""language_tags.py"""
from django import template
from django.urls import reverse, resolve
from django.utils import translation
from django.conf import settings

register = template.Library()

class TranslatedURL(template.Node):
    """gets current path and creates new url with passed language code.
    Is used by translate_url tag"""
    def __init__(self, language):
        self.language = language
    def render(self, context):
        language_value = self.language.resolve(context)
        view = resolve(context['request'].path)
        request_language = translation.get_language()
        translation.activate(language_value)
        url = reverse(view.url_name, args=view.args, kwargs=view.kwargs)
        translation.activate(request_language)
        return url

@register.tag(name='translate_url')
def do_translate_url(parser, token):
    """creates path to current page with given language
    usage: {% translate_url <language code> %}"""
    language = token.split_contents()[1]
    language = template.Variable(language)
    return TranslatedURL(language)
```

The problem is that when using this on a page with a form, all the user inputs made so far get lost because of the page being reloaded completely again.

I came up with the idea that I can add these inputs to the url;
e.g. `de/product/product_id/?name=product_name&description=this is a prduct`
so that if given they can be added as initial data when the view is loaded.

But I can't come up with an idea or find anything related, how to fetch the user's input when I am in the `translate_url` template tag in `templatetags/language_tags.py`